# Pass extra info to custom action mailer delivery class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a 3rd party email integration library that I want to use to send email *as* one of my users. To send email I make an API call using an `access_token` that I save for each user.

To still use action mailer, I've created a custom delivery class like this:

```
module Mail
  class CustomMailDelivery
    attr_reader :settings

    def initialize(settings)
      @settings = settings
    end

    def deliver!(mail)
      # use 3rd party client here
    end
  end
end
```

I'm configuring this in an initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :custom, Mail::CustomMailDelivery, {
  app_id: ENV.fetch('3RDPARTY_APP_ID'),
  app_secret: ENV.fetch('3RDPARTY_APP_SECRET'),
}
```

This allows me to set the delivery method on a per-mailer basis:

```
class LeadMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.delivery_method = :custom

  ...
end
```

The problem is, I need to pass the user that is sending this message along, so I can get their `access_token`.

I don't want to rely on fetching the `EmailAccount` using the sender's email address because it seems like this could break down the road (it's possible this email address *might* not be the same as the sending user). 
In other words, I'd like to pass it explicitly, so it is easy to understand and I avoid any confusion.

Is there a way to provide per-mail context to a custom action mailer delivery class?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up passing this data with a custom message header, which I later delete when handling the message.

```
class CustomMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.delivery_method = :custom

  attr_reader :sending_account

  def mail(params)
    raise 'You must call set_sending_account before calling mail.' unless sending_email_account
    super(params.merge({
        Mail::CustomMailDelivery::ACCOUNT_ID_HEADER => sending_account.id
      }))
  end

  def set_sending_account(account)
    @sending_account = account
  end
end
```

This way mailers that need this behavior subclass from this class and are forced to provide the custom data.

In the delivery class I yank this value out of the headers:

```
module Mail
  class CustomMailDelivery
    attr_reader :settings

    # we'll hijack email headers in order to pass over some required data from the mailer to this class
    ACCOUNT_ID_HEADER = '__account_id'

    def initialize(settings)
      @settings = settings
    end

    def deliver!(mail)
      account = account_for(mail)
      client = third_party_api_client(account.access_token)
      client.send_message(...)
    end

    private

    def third_party_api_client(access_token)
      # ...
    end

    def account_for(mail)
      header_field = mail[ACCOUNT_ID_HEADER]
      missing_account_id_header! unless header_field
      email_account = Account.find(header_field.value)

      # remove the header field so it doesn't show up in the actual email
      mail[ACCOUNT_ID_HEADER] = nil

      account
    end

    def missing_account_id_header!
      raise "Missing required header: #{ACCOUNT_ID_HEADER}"
    end
  end
end
```

This solution is not very elegant, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the idea, I put together a shorter version by using `register_observer` and `register_interceptor`.

It's basically the same idea, except you don't need to redefine too much delivery stuff. You just hook in the mail workflow.

First, declare the hook:

```rb
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailToActionEventObserver)
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailToActionEventObserver)
```

Then, the easy part is that the hooks are static methods inside of the same class:

```
class MailToActionEventObserver
  def self.delivered_email(mail)
    # Here you can use @passed_argument because it is called just after
    # self.delivering_email
  end

  def self.delivering_email(mail)
    @passed_argument = mail['MY-PERSONAL-HEADER'].to_s
    # Now remove the temporary header:
    mail['MY-PERSONAL-HEADER'] = nil
  end
end
```

Now, same as your answer @Ben, just need to pass the argument as a header in the mailer:

```
def my_custom_mail
  headers['MY-PERSONAL-HEADER'] = 'whatever-value'
  mail(...)
end
```